# Preventing the page from being highlighted when clicking and holding shift on a browser

Tags: html, css, select

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent a web page from being highlighted when holding the shift key and clicking anywhere on the browser (this happens in Safari, not sure if it does on any other website), I would like to prevent this from happening in Safari. If it works on the browsers that's a plus.

Go ahead and try it on this page. Hold shift and click anywhere. See the highlighted portion? YUCK!! Any help would be much appreciated! thanks in advance!

here's the layout of my HTML page

```
<html>

<body>
<div id="content">
<!---- Some random stuff ----->
 </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's two clicks I believe. One shift-click at the beginning, another at the end of the text block you want to select.

Comment: Three things:  1.  Why would you want to prevent the highlighting of text on your page?  2.  Why not just put the text in an image?  and 3.  Here's a tip:  Posting a useless "layout of [your] HTML page" and lazily expecting us to fill it in for you is a great way to get your question down-voted and closed.

Comment: @esqew, if you hold shift and click over text you'll see What I'm talking about. And it also does it on double click too. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack Maney: 1. I'm creating a web editor that has some functionality that allows you to select two items while clicking one, then the other. Highlighting the page makes it look really bad. 2. I'm not trying to prevent copying from happening, in fact I want it to happen... not while a specific event is happening though. 3. It's to represent the structure of my web page. the commented section represents items that will be added and remove dynamically, I have no way of knowing what the user will add or removed. and finally: I appreciate your concern but assure you that its for the best intention

Comment: @JackManey: I try not to spend too much time on details that will cause readers not to answer the question, I much rather get to the point. If What I'm using it for has nothing to do with what I want accomplished. It's a simple question that I had trouble with because I thought it had something to do with `prevent-default` but had no success. Jack, I hope this is sufficient information for you. Peace and Love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I should tell you this probably isn't a good idea because users expect this basic website functionality to be consistent and always work. Just because you think it is yuck, doesn't mean everyone does.

With that out of the way, you will want to add some CSS, use  `user-select: none;`, typically with all the usual vendor prefixes such as `moz`, `webkit`, `o`, etc.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCCdh/).

[Further Reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select).

Comment: I can add this property and remove this dynamically?

Comment: @FelipeTadeo: Yes, you should be able to.

Comment: I do want them to but I would like to prevent it while a specific event is happening (a function that is called when a specific Boolean  is true.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using the css property `user-select` and setting that to none while the mouse is clicked and the shift key is pressed.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/E2dfk/